# Can't use PR2 Navigation Stack

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow 'PR2 Navigation Stack Demo' in pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls.

Unfortunately, it does not work on my computer (Ubuntu + groovy).

- I have done to rosmake every required packages.
- When I type 'roslaunch ~/pr2_nav_tutorial.launch', I got the following error messages:

process[interpolate_missing_tilt_laser_data_filter-6]: started with pid [28137]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_navigation_self_filter/self_filter]: can't locate node [self_filter] in package [pr2_navigation_self_filter]
process[base_shadow_filter-8]: started with pid [28143]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_navigation_self_filter/self_filter]: can't locate node [self_filter] in package [pr2_navigation_self_filter]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [semantic_point_annotator/sac_inc_ground_removal_node]: can't locate node [sac_inc_ground_removal_node] in package [semantic_point_annotator]

...

File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_navigation/pr2_move_base/scripts/pr2_move_base.py", line 45, in 
from pr2_msgs.msg import LaserTrajCmd
ImportError: No module named pr2_msgs.msg
[r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_generator-12] process has died [pid 28721, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_common_actions/joint_trajectory_generator/bin/joint_trajectory_generator __name:=joint_trajectory_generator __log:=/home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/r_arm_controller-joint_trajectory_generator-12.log].
log file: /home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/r_arm_controller-joint_trajectory_generator-12*.log
[l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_generator-13] process has died [pid 28746, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_common_actions/joint_trajectory_generator/bin/joint_trajectory_generator __name:=joint_trajectory_generator __log:=/home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/l_arm_controller-joint_trajectory_generator-13.log].
log file: /home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/l_arm_controller-joint_trajectory_generator-13*.log

- Despite the error messages,  it constantly generates the following pattern of logs:

[tilt_shadow_filter-5] process has died [pid 29406, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/laser_filters/bin/scan_to_cloud_filter_chain scan:=tilt_scan cloud_filtered:=tilt_scan_shadow_filtered __name:=tilt_shadow_filter __log:=/home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/tilt_shadow_filter-5.log].
log file: /home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/tilt_shadow_filter-5*.log
respawning...
[tilt_shadow_filter-5] restarting process
process[tilt_shadow_filter-5]: started with pid [29489]
[base_shadow_filter-8] process has died [pid 29422, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/laser_filters/bin/scan_to_cloud_filter_chain scan:=base_scan cloud_filtered:=base_scan_shadow_filtered __name:=base_shadow_filter __log:=/home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/base_shadow_filter-8.log].
log file: /home/jiwung/.ros/log/4f4c7f06-0aad-11e4-beb3-a01d48be97cc/base_shadow_filter-8*.log
respawning...
[base_shadow_filter-8] restarting process
process[base_shadow_filter-8]: started with pid [29505]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
what():  Could not find library corresponding to plugin pr2_navigation_perception/PR2PointCloudFootprintFilterNew. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
what():  Could not find library corresponding to plugin pr2_navigation_perception/PR2PointCloudFootprintFilterNew. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.

- So, ignoring the error messages, I typed 'roslaunch pr2_navigation_global rviz_move_base.launch', but the pr2 robot does not appear in rviz. Under Display tap, Status of RobotModel is labeled with Error.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186421/can%27t-use-pr2-navigation-stack/) by [kenomuseki](https://answers.ros.org/users/19583/kenomuseki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-14**:
What is being done to launch the PR2? I think these tutorials require the minimal PR2 to be brought up before they can be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The errors you're getting indicate that the nodes you're trying to run don't exist; either they aren't built they aren't in a package on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

This really looks like you haven't built your packages properly. Are you certain the rosmake process was successful?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kenomuseki](https://answers.ros.org/users/19583/kenomuseki/) on 2014-07-13**:
I checked the packages by typing 'rospack find':

$ rospack find pr2_navigation_self_filter
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_navigation/pr2_navigation_self_filter
$ rospack find semantic_point_annotator
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_navigation/semantic_point_annotator

Is there something else I should check?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-13**:
You should look to make sure that the nodes themselves are built in those packages; probably within the bin/ dir of the package. Since your package directories is in /opt/ros/, I assume you've installed pr2_navigation from debs?